# Javascript error "htmlfile: Access is denied" on form submit

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

When trying to do post back when the user press to close my modal web page window in IE8  by the Javascript command `form.submit` calling from the event handler of `onbeforeunload`, I get the error:

> "htmlfile: Access is denied".

What to do?

```
<script language='javascript' for='window' event='onbeforeunload()'>
if (this.event.clientY<0){__doPostBack('__Page','__close')}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var theForm = document.forms['MyModalForm'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.MyModalForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

    theForm.submit();//ERROR: Access is denied  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

}
}
// -->
</script>
```

I am using windows7, iis7.5, asp.net4.0.

Comment: Will you please provide your code? I cannot help you without a lot of details. Plus, your sentence is very long and unclear.

Comment: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/03/10/fileupload-and-htmlfile-access-is-denied-error/